# "Happy new year to you and your broker who [are trusting | have trusted | trust] us for so many years

Tags: conjugation

Which is the correct form?
The source text uses "are trusting" but I feel it should be "have trusted".

Comment: The use of "are trusting" sounds very Indian English to me. Do you know whether the author was Indian and/or aiming at an Indian audience?

Comment: No the author is a French coworker. I have to integrate a page in our corporate website with this text and wanted to be sure before doing so. The audience is international.

Comment: Then "are trusting" is not standard usage. "have trusted" is acceptable, but implies nothing about the present. "have been trusting" would possibly be slightly better, as it means that they still trust you (and presumably will continue to do so). That's the grammar done with; now the (off-topic) advice: The whole sentence just sounds a bit weird to me (British English native speaker): you don't normally tell people that they trust you! I'd prefer something along the lines of "Happy New Year to you and your broker. Thank you for the many years of business, and we look forward to many more".

Comment: I did not think about "have been trusting" but it indeed sounds better. You should maybe make it an answer. Regarding the rest of your comment, I prefer to only correct clear mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sentence contains the time preposition **for**, the action started in the past and is continuing up until now.Therefore I agree that **have trusted** is the most suitable choice.